# How to return an integer from a variable in Java?

Tags: java, static, void

I've never written a single line of Java in my life and I'm trying to help my son return a random number between 0-100. I figured out how to write it to the console but not how to return the actual value out of his method so he can use it. I think it has something to do with the crazy void, static, or ways ya'll write your functions. That's all Greek to me (er, java to me). Coming from Javascript I fixed that up for him in 10 secs but this has now really stumped me since I know nothing about Java.

The code is below and I want to give him some kind of return so he can use the number in the program he's writing.

```
import java.util.Random;
public class generateRandom{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        // create instance of Random class
        Random rand = new Random();
        // Generate random integer in range 0 to 100
        int rand_int1 = rand.nextInt(101);
        // Print random integers
        System.out.println("Random Integer: "+rand_int1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, there is not much point in writing a separate method; calling it does not get much simpler than `rand.nextInt(101)`. Note that the creation of the `Random` object should not be done for each random number but just once.

Comment: That's a good point. Now that I know how to get where he wants to go in the "dirty" way, I'll have him learn how to clean it up and make it more efficient. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start by adding a `static` method like:

```
public static int computeRandom() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    return rand.nextInt(101);
}
```

and then invoke that method from your `main()`.

But thing is: there are no detours in life. The real answer is: even if you just want "some small thing", you will have to invest the time and energy to learn *enough* to make that happen.

Comment: I actually had this at 3am last night but being an idiot I took nothing happening as an error. It's really that I created a function and then never freaking called the thing. Of course it's no output. So your comment gave me that click so I could shift that system print and the call to the main and now it returns correctly. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a separate method here return the random value and pass it around or you can just pass the rand_int variable as a argument to the function you want to use.